# Elasticsearch: Possible to process aggregation results?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, summarization

I calculate the duration of my service-processes using the SUM-Aggregation. Each step of the executed process will be saved in Elasticsearch under a calling Id.

This is what I monitor:

```
Duration of Request-Processing for ID #123 (calling service #1)

Duration of Server-Response for ID #123 (calling service #1)

**Complete Duration for ID #123**

Duration of Request-Processing for ID #124 (calling service #1)

Duration of Server-Response for ID #124 (calling service #1)

**Complete duration for ID #124**
```

Filter:

```
{
"from" : 0, "size" :0,

    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : { "match_all" : {}},
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "callingId" : "123",
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "total_duration" : { "sum" : { "field" : "duration" } },
        "max_duration":{"max": {"field":"duration"}},   
        "min_duration":{"min":{"field":"duration"}}
        }
    }
    }
```

This returns the complete duration of the process and also tells me which part of the process was the fastest ans which part was the slowest.

Next I want to calculate the average **duration of all finished processes** by serviceId. In this case I only care about the total duration for each service, so I can comepare them.

**How can I create the average, minimum and maximum from my total_durations?**

EDIT: I added some sample Data, I hope you can work with it.

Call1:

```
{
"callerId":"U1",
"operation":"Initialize",
"status":"INITIALIZED",
"duration":1,
"serviceId":"1"
}

{
"callerId":"U1",
"operation":"Calculate",
"status":"STARTED",
"duration":1,
"serviceId":"1"
}

{
"callerId":"U1",
"operation":"Finish",
"status":"FINISHED",
"duration":1200,
"serviceId":"1"
}

sum: 1202
```

Call2:

```
{
"callerId":"U2",
"operation":"Initialize",
"status":"INITIALIZED",
"duration":2,
"serviceId":"1"
}

{
"callerId":"U2",
"operation":"Calculate",
"status":"STARTED",
"duration":1,
"serviceId":"1"
}

{
"callerId":"U2",
"operation":"Finish",
"status":"FINISHED",
"duration":1030,
"serviceId":"1"
}

sum: 1033
```

**Aggregation for All Service-Calls for Service ID #1**
This is what I want to calculate:

```
Max: 1202
Min: 1033
AVG: 1116
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data? And the mapping of your index?

Comment: done, I hope it is helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit more complicated, but here it goes (only in 1.4 because of [this type of aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html)):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "serviceId": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "executionTimes": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "_agg['values'] = new java.util.HashMap();",
        "map_script": "if (_agg.values[doc['callerId'].value]==null) {_agg.values[doc['callerId'].value]=doc['duration'].value;} else {_agg.values[doc['callerId'].value].add(doc['duration'].value);}",
        "combine_script":"someHashMap = new java.util.HashMap();for(x in _agg.values.keySet()) {value=_agg.values[x]; sum=0; for(y in value) {sum+=y}; someHashMap.put(x,sum)}; return someHashMap;",
        "reduce_script": "finalArray = []; finalMap = new java.util.HashMap(); for(map in _aggs){for(x in map.keySet()){if(finalMap.containsKey(x)){value=finalMap.get(x);finalMap.put(x,value+map.get(x));} else {finalMap.put(x,map.get(x))}}}; finalAvgValue=0; finalMaxValue=-1; finalMinValue=-1; for(key in finalMap.keySet()){currentValue=finalMap.get(key);finalAvgValue+=currentValue; if(finalMinValue<0){finalMinValue=currentValue} else if(finalMinValue>currentValue){finalMinValue=currentValue}; if(currentValue>finalMaxValue) {finalMaxValue=currentValue}}; finalArray.add(finalMaxValue); finalArray.add(finalMinValue); finalArray.add(finalAvgValue/finalMap.size()); return finalArray",
        "lang": "groovy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I'm not saying it's the best approach, but only one I could find. Also, I'm not saying that the solution is in its best form. Probably, it may be cleaned up and improved. I wanted to show, though, that it is possible. Keep in mind, though, it's available in 1.4.

The basic idea of the approach is to use the scripts to build a data structure that should hold the information you need, computed in different steps according to [scripted metric aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). Also, the aggregation is performed for only one `serviceId`. If you want to do this for all serviceIds I think you might want to re-think a bit the data structure in the scripts.

For the query above and for the exact data you provided the output is this:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 6,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "executionTimes": {
         "value": [
            1202,
            1033,
            "1117.5"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The order of values in the array `value` is [max, min, avg], as per the script in `reduce_script`.

Comment: Fantastic! I was hoping for an approach like this until the Reducers will arrive in Version 2.0.0 . I will give it a try. Since I trust your answer I'll accept it right away. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There will be a new feature in upcoming version 2.0.0 called "**Reducers**". Reducers will allow you to calculate aggregations over aggregations.

Related Post:
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8110