# Elasticsearch: Autocomplete on the available buckets in an aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

boiled down to its essence the problem is that

- I have a multi-valued field of unanalysed strings (consider them as `tags`)
- I have an aggregation, which collects these tags

Now the requirement is to be able to filter these aggregations by `tags` (which is the easy part) and provide prefix search on the set of available `tags` (the hard part) to have a neat drill-down feature.

If I do a naive filter on the prefix (e.g. "Ge") of a `tag`

```
   "aggregations": {
      "tags": {
         "filter": {
            "prefix": {
               "tags": "Ge"
            }
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "tags": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "tags"
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

it returns all `tags` that occur in a field where at least one `tag` starts with "G".

Is there a way to fix that other than retrieve to many `tags` and then prefix-filter them "by hand". btw if think scripting like in [Elasticsearch: Possible to process aggregation results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992154/elasticsearch-possible-to-process-aggregation-results) should not be necessary.

thanks
markus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter aggregated values by using "include" parameter. As value of this parameter you need to pass regular expression. For your example it will be:

```
"aggregations": {
      "tags": {
         "filter": {
            "prefix": {
               "tags": "Ge"
            }
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "tags": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "tags",
                  "include": "Ge.*"
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

This should return tags starting with "Ge".

Link to documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values

Comment: thanks a lot - somehow I missed that last filter (in the filtered term aggregation, which itself is filtered).  :-)